# Hub R claiming Ps are getting a message that a webcam is needed for an unmoderated task

Tags: email, product

In [this project](https://www.userinterviews.com/projects/47307/staff/settings) the R is claiming that Ps are seeing a screen when confirming themselves for the project that tells them they'll need a webcam to complete the study, when that's not requested in the characteristics or anywhere else. Any idea where that might be coming from? Have pushed back for a screenshot but not received one yet.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is this even about programming? Can you post your code? The "project" link is inaccessible to me as it takes me to a login page. Why is it tagged "email" and "product"? You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that when the Researcher set up the "Technical Requirements" they indicated "Computer with Webcam" as the device type:
[image]

This Device Type is shown in a number of places as "Device Requirements" to the participant (e.g. the browse page, session confirmation page, etc.):
[image]